# Designing a multi-language searchable translation database

Tags: database-design, architecture

Good morning,

I am currently building an application where I have different sets of terms(yes could be sentences) or words represented in different languages.

Example:

```
english | french | german | latin
----------------------------------
cat     | chat   | katze  | feles
dog     | chien  | hund   | canem
```

etc..
I want to allow the user to input the query in one language and select which language to translate to, and the other way around. The functionality is very similar to that of Google translate.

At the same time, I need to maintain a cache for all languages combined as I would be implementing an auto-suggest feature on input. The users will be writing their query and the language will be automatically deduced based on input.

I need some advice regarding how and where(recommended DBMS) to store this information in a way that makes retrieval of data as fast as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: can you try rephrasing "I need to maintain a cache for all languages combined as I would be implementing an auto-suggest feature on input". I'm not sure on what you mean.

Comment: Basically there will be one input field with autocomplete. The uaer can input a word in any language and the suggestions will be based on what the user inputs.